# Regular expression removing 000 and retaining numbers, minus and comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like follows in javascript-

```
var input="-213,23.3 '000 Millions";
```

I want the output to be "-213,23.3"
I am using following regex to achieve this-

```
input.replace(/[^0-9.,'-]/g, "")
```

But I am getting output "-213,23.3'000"

I want to remove **'000** also(as I this is a representation of thousand)

Can anybody please tell me how to remove **'000** with retaining **numbers**,**'-'**(minus),**','**(comma)
Thanks in advance

PS: I just want to add one more conditon for **'000** to existing regex because I can not afford to change this regex.

Comment: Why regex? Use `input.split(' ')[0]`

Comment: because it is not necessary that every time i get a blank space between number and '000(sorry!forgot to mention :P)

Comment: Okay, try `input.match(/(.+)'/)[1];`

Comment: @Tushr there's an extra space in the end

Comment: Why not match it [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/wffu2smj/1/)?

Comment: Do you always have `'000` in your string? What are other possible inputs? What is the number delimeter if there is no space?

Comment: *I can not afford to change this regex* - then how can you even add a "condition" to this regex? Please post full relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
input.replace(/^(-?[\d,]+(?:\.\d+)?).*$/, "$1")
```

Or as an additional condition on your regex:

```
input.replace(/[^0-9.,'-]+|'\d+/g, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input="-213,23.3 '000 Millions";    
var a = input.replace(/\ ?\'(.*?)$/, '');
console.log(a);
```

or

```
var a = input.replace(/\ ?\'[\s\S]+$/, '');
```

Comment: None of those can work if there is no space; the result: `-213,23.3'000`